# How to make Google Cloud Storage direct download links compliant with ACLs?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

If a .txt file is saved to GCS and clicked on through the developer console browser by an authorized user, the contents are displayed in the web browser. That's fine, but that URL can be sent to *anyone*, authorized or not, allowing them to view the contents of the file.

"Share publicly" is unchecked, and no changes have been made to the default ACLs. And this isn't specific to .txt files -- that's just the easiest way to replicate the behavior since they're displayed directly in the browser (so you can easily get to that URL).

How do I configure GCS to either disable direct download links or ensure they're compliant with ACLs?

EDIT: It appears that the link expires after a few minutes, which reduces the associated risk *a little*, but not entirely. I'm still extremely nervous about how easily an authorized user could use this to inadvertently provide an unauthorized user direct access to something they ought not...

Comment: Have you gone though this part of the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#cookieauth?

Comment: @Price Yes. It describes a scenario where the person you're sending the link to will be prompted for their credentials, must log in, and must have been granted access before they'll see the object. That would be great. In this case, none of those checks seem to apply.

Comment: In that case, it seems only Google can do something about it. Probably open an issue?

Comment: Yeah, except that I don't think it's a bug. It's so universal and easy to replicate that I expect it's by design. But it would surprise me if it can't be reconfigured more securely -- I'm hoping someone here knows the magic code or configuration to do that.

Comment: If an authorized user has access to read a file (whether via URL, API, or CLI), they can download it and share it with anyone else. If you don't trust users to keep this data private, don't give them access to this data in the first place.

Comment: @MishaBrukman Yeah, I understand the theory behind that, and I trust my admins to be honest. I get concerned when it becomes so easy to cause an inadvertent breach. In this case, right-clicking on the file name in the console browser gives you a URL that's safe to share because it honors ACLs. But left-clicking on the filename and copying the URL from the browser bar gives you a URL that does *not* honor ACLs. This is precisely how I discovered the issue. It can be mitigated with training, but when dealing with very sensitive data, I prefer not to rely on human factors, don't you?  :-)

Comment: @MichaelAmes: good point and thanks for the feedback! I'll pass it on to the GCS team.

Answer (score 3):

## Left vs. right-clicking on files

First, regarding the difference between left-or-right clicking: I could not establish a difference between left- or right-clicking on a filename in the Google Cloud Storage storage browser.

To verify this, I opened a Google Cloud Project and opened a private object in a private bucket and opened it using both methods. I copied the URLs and opened them in a Chrome incognito window, where I was not logged in, to verify that my ACLs were not applied.

I was able to see both of the URLs in the incognito window. After some time, my access to them expired. However, interestingly enough, my access to them expired just as well in the window where I was logged-in and authenticated to access Google Cloud Storage.

This is where things get interesting.

## Security and ACLs for user data in Google Cloud Storage browser

**TL;DR:** I believe the behavior you observed, namely that the URL can be viewed by anyone, is working as intended and it cannot be changed beyond what Google Cloud Storage already does with automatic timeouts; let me explain why.

When you are browsing Google Cloud Storage via the Developers Console, you are using the storage browser on the domain `console.developers.google.com` which means that you are authenticated with Google and proper ACLs can be applied to allow/deny access.

However, the only things you can view on that domain are bucket names, object names, and metadata, not the file content itself.

If Google were to serve you file content on the `google.com` domain, it would create a security issue by allowing an adversary to force your browser to execute Javascript on your behalf with your Google credentials, thus allowing them to do anything you can do through the web UI. This is typically referred to as an [XSS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

To disallow this from happening, Google Cloud Storage (and Google in general, e.g., cached web pages) serve user-originating data on a different domain, typically `*.googleusercontent.com`, where users can't take advantage of any sensitive cookies or credentials, since nothing that Google provides is served on the same domain.

However, as a result, since the data is being served from one domain (`*.googleusercontent.com`) but your authentication is on a different domain (`*.google.com`), there is no way to apply the standard Google Cloud Storage bucket or object ACLs to the file contents themselves, while protecting you from XSS attacks by malevolent users.

Thus, **ALL** users, even those that have direct access to the file, upon viewing them in their browser, will have the content served with a [time-limited signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs) on a different domain.

As a side-effect, this does allow users to copy-paste the URL and share it with others, who will have similar time-limited access to the file contents.

Comment: Right-vs-left: I should have been more specific. Right-click on the filename and choose "Copy Link Location." That's the "safe" link, at the domain console.developers.google.com. Pass that to a friend and it will honor ACLs.

As for the rest of the explanation, thanks -- it's helpful to understand. It's still unnerving that it's so easy to create a link to a "secure" object, and that link can circumvent ACLs. I'd hope this would be on a list somewhere in Google-land as an area to improve security.